# Add image to set property without saving it in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image, outlook

I have developed the code to generated outlook emails from stats data. Stuck at a problem where storing an image is required in the PC as it is needed for replacing the image in HTML outlook body to complete report. 
outlook part is achieved via 
Imports EAGetMail
Imports EASendMail
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Have tried mentioning the image differently have tried input stream also. None of it work while the 
Dim attach = OutlookMessage.Attachments.Add property is only accepting a path and not an image.

```
Dim captcha2 As Bitmap
 If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\output\Sa7e839.jpg") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete("C:\output\Sa7e839.jpg")
        End If

        captcha2.Save("C:\output\Sa7e839.jpg")


Dim attach = OutlookMessage.Attachments.Add("C:\output\Sa7e839.jpg") ' temp saved file. deletes on rerun of app 
attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "backlog") ' setting property
oMail.HtmlBody = oMail.HtmlBody.Replace("cid:image003.png@01D2B201.94F4FA80", "cid:backlog") ' replacing HTML
```

Expected Result: The image should not need to be saved and then attach as the path the image should moved directly from code to the outlook body mail.

Comment: You need to embed the image in the email, in which case you can refer to the embedded resource in the HTML of the message. https://www.bing.com/search?q=outlook+embed+image+in+email&PC=U316&cvid=00c1415bcc8641488c4783b04c006a13&&setLang=en-US&FORM=ANNTA1

Comment: No this cannot help. Attachment type as embedded is not available in Eagetmail.

Comment: No need to do delete, Save overwrites if you put the same filename.

Comment: Thanks But that's added for safety in case the file is already open in the mail then it might not be possible to delete it. Using method 
Outlookmessage.Display(False).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed images directly into HTML body - Outlook (which uses Word to render HTML messages) does not support base64 encoded images embedded into the HTML body - they must be added as attachments and referenced by the content id.

And attachments in OOM can only be added from the file system. If you want to create an attachment bypassing the file system, you'd need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language).